# startActivity in java class crash

Tags: java, android, start-activity

I'm developing an Android app for a school project and i have the following problem. I have a `MainActivity` with a `Button` and a `SecondActivity`. When I click on the button in the `MainActivity` it have to open the `SecondActivity`. I tested it on my two devices (samsung galaxy s9+ and asus zenfone2):

**MainActivity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    Button button;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        button=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button);

        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent intent=new Intent(MainActivity.this,SecondActivity.class)
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
}
}
```

This works fine on both devices and when i click on the button it correctly opens the SecondActivity.

The problem is when i add a controller class and try to start the `SecondActivity` in it. This is the controller class:

**Controller.java**

```
public class Controller {
    public void open(Context cont){
        Intent intent=new Intent(cont,SecondActivity.class);
        cont.getApplicationContext().startActivity(intent);
     }
  }
```

And I change the `MainActivity` this way:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    Button button;
    Controller c;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        button=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button2);
        c=new Controller();

        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                c.open(getApplicationContext());
            }
        });
}
}
```

This works fine on my s9+, while on my zenfone2 crashes when i click on the button. Where is the problem? if it's not correct, why works on s9+?

Thank you

Comment: public class controller {
    public void open(MainActivity cont){
        Intent intent=new Intent(cont,SecondActivity.class);
        cont.getApplicationContext().startActivity(intent);
     }
  } try this

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As of Android P you can't start an activity with the application context unless you add  Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK flag. So just change your controller and mainactivity to use the mainactivity context instead.

```
c.open(MainActivity.this);

public void open(Context context) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(context, SecondActivity.class);
    context.startActivity(intent);
}
```

Or

```
public void open(Context context) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(context.getApplicationContext(), SecondActivity.class);
    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    context.startActivity(intent);
}
```

Comment: Wow thank you so much!!! It works (also without flag). I've just changed c.open(getApplicationContext()) with c.open(MainActivity.this)

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
c.open(MainActivity.this);
```

and in Controller class do following :

```
public void open(Context cont){
        Intent intent=new Intent(cont,SecondActivity.class);
        cont.startActivity(intent);
     }
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply!!! It works but using MainActivity.this instead of MainActivity.class

Answer (score 0):

Remove `getApplicationContext()` from your Controller class in open function.
Make it `cont.startActivity(intent);`

Comment: Thanks for your'reply. I've just tried but it still crashes on zenfone2

Answer (score 0):

You cannot call `startActivity` from `getApplicationContext` anymore and you don't need to call it so many times.

Replace the `getApplicationContext` with "this".

```
button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                c.open(MainActivity.class);
            }
        });
```

and then just call startActivity

```
public class Controller {
    public void open(Context cont){
        Intent intent=new Intent(cont,SecondActivity.class);
        cont.startActivity(intent);
     }
  }
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I've tried to change the code how you suggest, but in the MainActivity changing 'getApplicationContext()' with 'this' i have the following error:  open(android.content.Context) in controller cannot be applied to (anonymous android.view.View.OnClickListener)

Comment: Ahhh sorry didn't notice it was anonymous. Corrected it. You need to call the outer class by name.